# Can you force Chrome / FF to a spec. width in full screen mode?

Tags: macos, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any kind of extension to make Chrome or Firefox a specific width while in full screen mode? For example like Pages does with it's full screen option.

It would be very nice to be able to have the browser viewport fixed to 1200 pixels, and then fill the rest in with a dark gray background. This would eliminate the desktop clutter while making it easier to browse. Most websites look awful full screen at 1920 pixels wide.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I was speaking of OSX Lion.